# Meteor: Iterate over cursor from MongoCollection.find() and print a field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm having trouble printing the contents that I am getting from a meteor collection. I have declared my collection in /ui/api/collections.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import 'meteor/aldeed:collection2';

export const Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");

Courses.allow({
    'insert': function () {
       // if (Meteor.isEducator(Meteor.userId())) {
            return true;
    }
})
```

/imports/api/course.html

```
<template name="course">
    <h2> You are enrolled in the following courses:</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each course_list}}
            {{> getCourseName}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="getCourseName">
    <li><h2>{{courseName}}</h2></li>
</template>
```

/imports/api/course.js

```
Template.course.helpers({
    course_list: function() {
        var result =  Courses.find({});
        console.log("result is:");
        console.log(result);

        return result;
    }
})
```

I have declared Courses as a new Mongo.Collection and imported that into /server/main.js I have then imported /imports/api/collections.js into course.js and course.html.

```
the console output of printing course_list's result is :
L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}
```

I noticed that it says LocalCollection which makes me think it isn't finding the actual collection. When I do a db.courses.find() on the serverside mongo console I am seeing the two courses that do exist in the collection and they both have a courseName field. I don't think that I need to publish/subscribe since I am declaring the collection in imports and then exporting the collection as a global var. I'm new to meteor and javascript in general so any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries. You had access to the data already. It's just that Meteor creates [local collections](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#local-collections) on the client side - the power of Minimongo. That is why you saw `LocalCollection` on the console instead of `Courses`, which you might be expecting.

Note as well that `find` on collections returns a [cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor). One needs to use operations *fetch*, *forEach*, *map*, etc to manipulate the actual data.